# vb.net error while trying to use OracleDataReader

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to get data from my Oracle Sql Developer server. The connection is OK but i seem to encounter a problem while trying to get the actual data from the DB. I keep getting the following error :
  *{"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"}*

The code i used is the following :

```
Public connectionString As String
Public sqlCom As String
Public command As New OracleCommand
Public con As New OracleConnection
Public dr As OracleDataReader
connectionString = "Data Source=orcl; User Id=system; Password=parola1234;"
con = New OracleConnection(connectionString)
Try
    con.Open()
    ''MessageBox.Show("succes")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
command.Connection = con
sqlCom = "select TICKETID from system.TICKETS where TICKETID = " + txtTicket.Text
command.CommandText = sqlCom
dr = command.ExecuteReader()
If (dr.HasRows) Then
   While (dr.Read())
       Me.Hide()
       GlobalVariables.ticketNOText = txtTicket.Text
       Tracking.Show()
   End While
Else
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Ticket Number!")
End If
```

Here is a picture of my SQL DB :
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iteQ.png)

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your previous 7 questions have 9 answers but none of them have been accepted.  Accepting answers and upvoting good posts (Q or A) helps other users find good answers.

Comment: your connecting as SYSTEM - your application objects and tables are probably in another schema - don't use SYSTEM for your app.